# Segment violation when Proxy-Authentication header is not empty

Tags: squid

When I'm trying to send curl request with provided basic proxy-authorization credentials through my proxy I see Segment Violation error in my logs and empty reply from server.
Command is:
*curl -v --proxy-basic --proxy-user login:password --proxy http://192.168.3.19:8080 https
://google.com*

In squid.conf I have 3 directives:

*http_access allow some_acl
http_access allow some_acl some_acl_user_auth some_special_domain http_all_port http_all_proto
http_access allow some_acl some_acl_user_auth some_special_domain CONNECT https_port*

If I comment first one authorization works fine and it looks good. But with all lines I even can't authorize to special domains without Segment Violation error.
I've tried to use different versions of squid from 3.5 to 7.0.
Squid before v5.0.1 ignores Proxy-Authorization header when it's not needed and works fine with this configuration.